# replace existing ssd drive with new one and reinstall system boot problems

Tags: boot, uefi, ssd

I try to replace my old, smaller SSD drive with a newer one, in my HP ENVY laptop http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03599931.pdf

The old `fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=093b4c4b-f536-4e00-a94d-e32831545f92 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=19f07f2e-5b4e-4901-98b9-112e110bad06 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=E9C1-2D75  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9336939d-156a-4411-b757-41820baa7676 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=348ea965-144b-478c-8835-6b43a5ad2f76 /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
#UUID=a575009a-7380-4d2e-9a72-507b91b2bb14 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
# map /tmp to memory
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=2048M       0       0
```

I replaced the SSD `/dev/sdb`. In BIOS I couldn't find anything related to activation of hard drives, however the kubuntu 16.04 installer found the new SSD just fine.

I installed the OS. It kept grumbling about EFI/compatibility modes etc. And I can't boot.

I tried installing with the EFI, without EFI, turned EFI on and off in BIOS. I still can't boot.

Then I tried to use boot repair tool which gave following output:
http://pastebin.com/raw/rBiqu7W1

And I still can't boot.

Some suggestions what I should try?

Comment: It looks like sdb is MBR(msdos) partitioned. And Linux install is on that drive. Use Boot-Repair's advanced mode, when booted in BIOS/CSM mode to reinstall grub to the MBR of sdb and set BIOS to boot sdb. Your sda is gpt and needs either an ESP for UEFI boot or a bios_grub for BIOS boot. Always boot Ubuntu live installer in the same mode your install is, always BIOS or always UEFI. Do not mix as they are incompatible (mostly).

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error I figured out that I didn't create UEFI partition at the beginning of my `/dev/sdb`

Strange, I would expect the installer should have warned me about that, not pass this silently...